# Express JS/ MongoDB Post not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I started working on a `MERN` App today and am trying to write a `restful api`. First I am using `mlab` to store my `mongodb` database. I have succesfully connected to this database after creating a user. I can manually create a `collection` and inject some data into this `collection`. From my `server.js` file I can then get the data stored in here.

```
MongoClient.connect(db_url, (err, database) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    var collection = database.collection('memories'); // Collection called memories
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("Listening on 3000");
    });
});
```

Thats all fine and dandy but I want to take it to the next level. I want to write a `CRUD` api for the collection `Memory`. Coming from `django`, I would like to create my `model` first. Therefore, in my `models/memory.js`:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MemorySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Memory', MemorySchema);
```

Then I went ahead and started working on my `routes/api/api.js`:

```
let router = require('express').Router();
let Memory = require('../../../models/memories');

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("Something is happening");
    next(); // Request stops at middleware without next()
});

router.route('/memory')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        let memory = new Memory();
        memory.name = req.body.name;
        memory.description = req.body.description;

        memory.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({message: 'Memory Created'});
        });
    })

    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.json({message: 'First memory'});
    });


module.exports = router;
```

And in my `server.js` I call this module:

```
const apiRoutes = require('./routes/api/api');
app.use('/api/', apiRoutes);
```

However, after testing the post api with `postman`, it the `POST` request just takes forever before showing up as `Could not get any response`. However, the `GET` request works. What am I missing?

EDIT: So the `post` function is having trouble saving the model instance...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `results` as the first parameter in the callback of the save function, then `res.json(results, { message: "Memory Created" })` to see if you are returned anything.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the post and the get method is that the post method uses Mongoose, while the get doesn't. If you fail to connect to the database then the response can time out due to `memory.save(...)` not working as it should. And there are no responses sent outside the callback to save, so if your program never enter it, you will never send a response. The request will time out eventually.

In your model file you register a model on the following line:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Memory', MemorySchema);
```

Mongoose will then look for data in the *memorys* collection. If you change it to

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Memory', MemorySchema, 'memories');
```

it will use the *memories* collection instead. This will make it consistent with the connection-to-db snippet you posted. I don't know if that will fix your issue though. I would suggest changing the connection code to

```
mongoose.connect(dburl, {
  useMongoClient: true
});
```

instead of the native mongo client. You can add these lines too

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose connected');
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Mongoose connection error: ' + err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
  console.log('Mongoose disconnected');
});
```

right after the connection code to help with debugging. Make sure you get connected when starting the app.

If you see an error similar to this `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` in the node terminal window, it might be because you are sending two responses in the post function. If an error occurs while saving it will enter the `if(err)` block, send a response async then go to the `res.json(...)` response and send that too.

So you have to return after sending the response to exit the function. Either like this

```
res.send(err);
return;
```

or like this

```
return res.send(err);
```

Same for the json response.

If that doesn't fix the problem you should either fire up the debugger (`node --inspect` or `nodemon --inspect`), or insert a `console.log('inside post');` inside the post function to see that you're actually entering it.